# How can I get my google-maps API key to display my Map in jsbin

Tags: google-maps-api-3, jsbin

I am trying to get my google map to display in jsbin so I can do some testing and development there rather than on my website but I can't get it to display and get the following message:
Google has disabled use of the Maps API for this application. See the Terms of Service for more information: http://www.google.com/intl/en-US_US/help/terms_maps.html.

I've edited the referrers for my key to include www.jsbin.com and jsbin.com but I still get the same message.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need a key, google maps v3 does not nessecarily require it. See **https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial?csw=1#api_key** :

> All Maps API applications* should load the Maps API using an API key.
>   Using an API key enables you to monitor your application's Maps API
>   usage, and ensures that Google can contact you about your application
>   if necessary. If your application's Maps API usage exceeds the Usage
>   Limits, you must load the Maps API using an API key in order to
>   purchase additional quota.

Notice the **should**. It is very unlikely you'll meet the 25.000 limit views per day when you are testing, so why not just forget about the key - like in this jsbin example -> **http://jsbin.com/jiboxaso/1/edit** ??

Comment: @davidkonrad strangely, the code you linked works, and it works also saved on local files. But, uploaded to my server it didn't. The only way to make it work on the server was: using an API key :)

Comment: @j.c, perhaps your server (IP) is known as host of other google maps services? Is the access to pages public, i.e if the pages holding google maps is behind a (payed) login you might need a key. The only time I have actually needed a key with google maps API3 is when I changed to [**leaflet**](http://leafletjs.com/) but still wanted to show google maps inside the leaflet framework.

Comment: @davidkonrad yeah, maybe... actually my server is a NAS with a dynamic IP, i'm using it remotely through a <my>.ddns.net domain... my API key refers to its actual IP. Maybe some other ddns user linked his "pay-service" API key to ddns domain...? BTW leaflet is really interesting!